# React rendering nested json

Tags: reactjs

I have some json looking like this

```
[
    {
    "name": "Hello Kitty",
    "items": [
        {
        "name": "Kitty Muu Muu"
      },
      {
        "name": "Kitty smack"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Hello Pussy",
    "items": [
            {
        "name": "World",
        "items": [
            {
            "name": "Hello Pussy world"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

it's nested JSON and my question is; where should the recursiveness be handled to render this?

I have 2 components
List component that calls the data and posts data changes back to the server

Item component that renders a single item

Should I handle this at the list level or item level?

The item renders an input field you can update and this should be possible both at parent and child level

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Item` to show child items(in `React` you can do it with `children` property), however main work will be in `List`, for example

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <li>
      { this.props.name }
      { this.props.children }
    </li>
  }
}

class List extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  list(data) {
    const children = (items) => {
      if (items) {
        return <ul>{ this.list(items) }</ul>
      }
    }

    return data.map((node, index) => {
      return <Item key={ node.id } name={ node.name }>
        { children(node.items) }
      </Item>
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <ul>
      { this.list(this.props.data) }
    </ul>
  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/140614/)

Comment: I posted a similar question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349417/converting-a-multi-level-json-menu-to-a-multi-level-jsx-html-menu - if you get a chance please check it out. Also, are both your Item class and your List class located in the same js file? Is there a benefit to having them in the same file as opposed to separate files?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in List component. If your List component is large, i would put them in another helper file to require it.

Comment: I realised that you can call a component within the same component, making it kinda recursive